# STM32F303 Discovery - USART_IT_RXNE Never recieve antyhing (No DMA/No HAL)

Tags: stm32, usart

I'm very new to both C code, and the STM platform; Im using it for a school project.
I have two card communication via USART (Specifically USART3). The Sensor card (Slave)'s job is to only send their current distance measurement. I have managed to set this up.
Via Scope, using RS232/UART communication mode, I can see the  hexe's being sent is "STX M 2 3 ETX"
Where the M is code for what kind of package it is, and the 2 and 3 is the hex 0x23 = 35 (cm). It sends a new measurement every 15ms.

Now to my problem. I cant seem to configure the Master's USART3 to recieve these packages.
This is my current code:

```
void USARTInit(void)
{
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
USART_ClockInitTypeDef  USART_ClockInitStructure;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure_UART,GPIO_InitStructure_UART_PD9;

//RCC_APB1Periph_AFIO;
//UART3 for communication with other STM (Master -> Slave / Master <- Slave)
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3, ENABLE);

USART_ClockStructInit(&USART_ClockInitStructure);
USART_ClockInit(USART3, &USART_ClockInitStructure);

USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 9600; //115200; //19200;//57600;//19200; //9600;
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;         //Word lenght, 8b = 8bit = 1byte
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;              //Num stoppbits
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity =  USART_Parity_No ;               //USART_Parity_Odd;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;     //Full duplex mode
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;

USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure);

//GPIO pins configuration
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOD, ENABLE);     //UART3 + TIM4

GPIO_InitStructure_UART.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;
GPIO_InitStructure_UART.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_AF;                  //Alternative func, here UART
GPIO_InitStructure_UART.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_Level_1;
GPIO_InitStructure_UART.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;                 //PushPull

GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure_UART);                         //Tx - Transmit
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_7);                //GPIO_AF_7 -> U(S)ART mode

GPIO_InitStructure_UART.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;
GPIO_InitStructure_UART.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure_UART.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;

GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure_UART);                         //Rx - Recieve
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_7);

USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);


USART_ITConfig(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_0);
NVIC_InitTypeDef nvicStructure;                             //Create a "extern" interupt base
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART3_IRQn;                //Link it to the global interupt of usart3
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;        //Unsure
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;               //The priority of this interupt if you have other external interupts
nvicStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;                  //enables it
NVIC_Init(&nvicStructure);                                  //Sends it to the Interupt handler

}
```

And my Handler code is :

```
void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
volatile uint16_t temp;
if (USART_GetITStatus(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET)
    {

    temp = USART_ReceiveData(USART3) & 0xff;                //0xFF ??? From datasheet
    USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE);

    }
**CODE TO COUNT BINARY USING 7 DIODEs**
}
```

The problem seems to be the `USART_ReceiveData(USART3)`, if I remove is I see that all the diodes are on constantly meaning something must must be going through this code over and over very quickly , but if I leave like it is, the first light turns on (ie first iteration) then nothing happens. Using my computer and adding a breakporints in the handler shows the temp variable always being empty. It only runs once then nothing. I suspect that a flag isnt being propely handled so Ive tried... some solutions.

```
//USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3,USART_IT_ORE);
//USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3, USART_IT_LBD);
//USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3, USART_IT_CTS);
//USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3, USART_IT_TC);
```

I had this code earlier but it made no difference.

Ive been trying now for 2 days to figure out whats wrong, but Im no closer than I was at the start. 
Ive tried googling it and have countless of different answers, but I cant ssem to find any that fixes my issue. Im sorry if the solution super obvious...

Comment: I do not own this board but two suggestions: 1) remove the line with USART_ClearITPendingBit 2) remove the bitwise operator from (& 0xff). If it works for you then I will submit a full answer with an explanation what was happening. If it does not work please try debugging with USART echo mode and first of all try receiving the data without using interrupts. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, the teacher come in to the lab to help me today, he showed me how to open the periphial view to see all kinds of additonal info. Apparently there were some flags toggled that shouldnt be (and since I didnt de-init it before configuration they stayed high) aswell as the pin used was being fought about since it was configured as a output somewhere else in another piece of the code. Sorry wasting you guys's time!

Comment: No worries, glad you have it working. Your last comment looks like a good answer to your question, maybe it is worth posting it as an answer ;). Cheers